# HTML Webpage POST to Server - waiting for response

Tags: html, post, serial-port, submit

I have a noob question - I have created a very simple HTML page to send a string of serial data over my network to a ethernet to serial converter when a button is pressed. This controls an audio matrix switch (via its serial port). The webpage works and it switches the audio matrix, but after I click a button, the browser is waiting indefinitely for a response. I can click other buttons and still make switches, but it is always waiting for a response. How can I get the response from this remote device and show it (or act on it) on the webpage, and keep the page from waiting indefinitely? Is this the correct way to send this data string to a remote IP, or is there a better way? Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#808080"> 
<div align="center">
&nbsp;<p><font size="7" face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Audio Control</font></p>
<div
<div style="width:500px;height:175px;border:1px solid white;">
<p align="left"><font size="6" face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Backyard</font></p><hr>
<form action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="Tuner" id="Backyard Tuner" name="CL1I1O1T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<form action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="Computer" id="Backyard Computer" name="CL1I2O1T"     class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<form action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="Apple TV" id="Backyard Apple TV" name="CL1I3O1T"  class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<form action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="iPod" id="Backyard iPod" name="CL1I4O1T" class="auto-     style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="Off" id="Backyard Off" name="DL1O1T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<p align="left">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="left">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="left">&nbsp;</p>
<div
<div style="width:500px;height:175px;border:1px solid white;">
<p align="left"><font size="6" face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Garage</font></p><hr>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="Tuner" id="Garage Tuner" name="CL1I1O2T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="Computer" id="Garage Computer" name="CL1I2O2T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="Apple TV" id="Garage Apple TV" name="CL1I3O2T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="iPod" id="Garage iPod" name="CL1I4O2T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="Off" id="Garage Off" name="DL1O2T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<div align="center"> 
<p align="left">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="left">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="left">&nbsp;</p>
<div
<div style="width:500px;height:175px;border:1px solid white;">
<p align="left"><font size="6" face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Family Room</font></p><hr>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="Tuner" id="Family Room Tuner" name="CL1I1O3T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="Computer" id="Family Room Computer" name="CL1I2O3T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="Apple TV" id="Family Room Apple TV" name="CL1I3O3T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="iPod" id="Family Room iPod" name="CL1I4O3T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="Off" id="Family Room Off" name="DL1O3T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<div align="center"> 
<p align="left">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="left">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="left">&nbsp;</p>
<div
<div style="width:500px;height:175px;border:1px solid white;">
<p align="left"><font size="6" face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Basement Family Room</font>      </p><hr>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="Tuner" id="Basement Tuner" name="CL1I1O4T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="Computer" id="Basement Computer" name="CL1I2O4T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="Apple TV" id="Basement Apple TV" name="CL1I3O4T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="iPod" id="Basement iPod" name="CL1I4O4T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
<action="http://192.168.5.30:100" method="POST" >
<font face="Arial">
<input type="submit" value="Off" id="Basement Off" name="DL1O4T" class="auto-style1" style="float: left" /><span class="auto-style1">
</span>
</font>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have any closing `</form>` tags.

Comment: And also - I don't think HTML page is able to form a proper string (without any "overhead" data) for your device...

Comment: David- Thanks for the reply! I am really new at HTML... I tried the same page with <form> at the beginning and </form> at the end, but it didnt seem to work at all, and it showed the data in the address bar. I also dont understand what you mean by "overhead data." I just kept researching, and trying everything I could find until I got it to work. Am I going about this the wrong way? I tried using PHP, but could never get sockets to work right.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing anything about your switch or Ethernet converter, but HTTP request is more then just string you sent from HTML form. There are loads of HTTP headers.

Comment: Basically, the switch has a serial port. I can connect with PuTTY and send the string "CL1I2O4T" and it will patch the audio (CL1), Input 2 (I2) to output 4 (O4) and commit (T).

Comment: The ethernet to serial converter lets me do the same thing over ethernet - I can connect with PuTTY to the ethernet address of the converter and do the same function. My goal is to have a web page that I can make these changes to the audio matrix. I have each button on the web page programmed with the proper string to patch the audio where I want it. Does the POST command wait for a response back after sending the data? I apologize for my lack of knowledge... I have read and learned a lot, but I am stuck on this part so far.

Comment: PuTTY? That's better. So, it supports telnet, I guess? I'll tell you what to do in answer below, it would be too big for comment.

Comment: Here you are. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

1) Set up Apache web server with PHP

2) Download [PHP Telnet](http://www.geckotribe.com/php-telnet/) script (or any other Telnet library for PHP)

3) Modify string

```
    if ($this->fp=fsockopen($ip,23)) {
```

to

```
    if ($this->fp=fsockopen($ip,100)) {
```

(your device responds to port 100 as I understand?)

4) Make PHP script with something like this (replace `username` and `password` with your credentials):
**proxy.php**

```
<?php
require_once "PHPTelnet.php";
$telnet = new PHPTelnet();
$command = $_GET['command'];
$result = $telnet->Connect('192.168.5.30:100','username','password');
if ($result == 0) {
$telnet->DoCommand($command, $result);
echo $result;
$telnet->Disconnect();
}
?>
```

5) Make HTML page similar to this (this one's very basic, just to give you idea and replace `yourhost` with IP of your webserver):

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://yourhost/proxy.php" method="GET">
Enter command 
<input type="text" name="command">
<input type="Submit">
</form>

<form action="http://yourhost/proxy.php" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" value="CL1I3O1T" id="Backyard Apple TV" name="command" />
<input type="Submit" value="Apple TV">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Copy last part of HTML file to add another commands. Put actual command in `value` of `hidden` input and label in `value` of `submit` input.

Comment: You are a genius! Unfortunately I am not! Haha... but seriously... I made the script and html page. I am testing this on my laptop, and I have PHP working on XAMPP. When I load proxy.php, I get the following error: Notice: Undefined index: command in S:\xampp\htdocs\720new\proxy.php on line 4

[PHP Telnet] Connect failed: Unknown host

Comment: I have been reverse engineering all of the HTML code I have used so far, but PHP is all new to me. I successfully connected to the device with telnet on port 100, using PuTTY. When I enter a command, the remote device echoes it back. So in my mind, telnet to the device works, but I am not sure how to troubleshoot the PHP script. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, there is no username or password on the remote device. This is the device I am using on the remote end: http://www.startech.com/Networking-IO/Serial-over-IP/1-Port-RS-232-422-485-Serial-over-IP-Ethernet-Device-Server~NETRS2321E

Comment: `Undefined index: command` means we  are not supplying `command` variable in URL. I tested my script and got it only when you press `Submit` without entering command in input string, which I gave to you to manually enter commands (for testing purposes)

Answer (score 0):

I know this post isn't tagged PHP, but I finally got this problem solved with PHP sockets. This web page will respond to a web page button press, open a socket to a remote IP, send a string of data, and finally close the socket. As I mentioned originally, the remote device is an ethernet to serial converter, which is connected to an audio switcher. I can now control this ethernet connected / serial controlled audio switcher using a PHP webpage. The code is pretty simple, but getting the syntax correct was difficult. Thanks to all of those who helped! I hope this helps someone else... Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<?php

$input=$_POST['input'];
$sock = fsockopen('192.168.5.30:100', NULL, $errno, $errstr);
fwrite($sock, $input);
echo fread($sock, 4096)."\n";
fclose($sock);
?>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="input" id="button" value="CL1I1O1T" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="input" id="button" value="CL1I2O1T" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="input" id="button" value="CL1I3O1T" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="input" id="button" value="CL1I4O1T" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="input" id="button" value="CL1I5O1T" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="input" id="button" value="CL1I6O1T" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="input" id="button" value="CL1I7O1T" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="input" id="button" value="CL1I8O1T" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="input" id="button" value="DL1O1T" />
<br />
<br />
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```